# Mesh getting ripped apart when remeshing

Tags: mesh, import, sculpting, remesh

I am new to Blender so please bear with me.  I have imported a model from Maya into blender as an fbx file. In sculpting mode when I try to remesh it Blender either stops responding or the mesh does something very odd where it looks like the mesh has been torn apart.  I attached an image to show what I mean.  Does anybody know what is happening here and how to fix this?  Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remesh doesn't work when you have "thin" mesh. Your model gotta have thickness more, than one face. Solutions:

1. Use multires modifier, not remeshing a surface
2. Add thickness to model by "solidify" modifier and applying that
3. Close all holes in your model and try to remesh ones more.

(here is a simple representation of why it appears. left cube has "hole" and just don't remesh properly)

[image]